# Why is the partial view called by my action from ajax.beginform not appearing on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a page which has a viewmodel, on the page the clicking of a button is submitting an ajax form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("finalstatus", "User", null, new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                    OnSuccess = "popupappear()",

                }, new { id = "progForm"}))
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.SectionID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.CourseID)
                }
```

This uses the controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult finalstatus(SubSectionViewModel model)
    {

        string currentuser = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        var viewModel = db.enrollment
            .Where(i => i.UserID == currentuser)
            .Where(i => i.course.CourseID == model.CourseID)

            .Select(x => new CurrentProgressViewModel
            {

                ovpcnt = (int)Math.Round((double)(100 * x.progress.Sum(c => c.progress)) / x.course.course_sections.SelectMany(i => i.course_subsections).Sum(c => c.scenes)),

            }).Single();


        return PartialView("_endofsection", viewModel);

    }
```

This should calculate the progress percentage for the user and return that percentage in a partial view "_endofsection" to the page.  The partial view uses the CurrentProgressViewModel which is holding the percentage.

Everything seems to work, however the partial view seems to not be loaded on the page, I can see it is being accessed and previews correctly in the network tab of google chrome.  However it does not appear on the page where the form is, which is where I would expect the partialview to load.

What am I missing here?  Why is this not appearing?

Additionally the onsuccess function that is called when the form submits successfully appears to only be called on the second click, however this is a secondary issue.

Comment: You are getting the response, but when are you rendering the partial view?...

Comment: I was under the illusion that returning the partial would render it, but now I think about it that doesn't make much sense.  I suppose I would have to use Html.Action to render it as it's a different model to the page.  That unfortunately is going to cause some issues.

Comment: I almost post an answer similar to the one provided by @Shyju.....the important thing is that you get the point, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making an ajax call using `Ajax.BeginForm` helper method. So you need to specify where the response (of the ajax call) to be replaced in the DOM. You can specify that using the `UpdateTargetId` property.  It should be the Id of the element to which you want to add the response coming back from your ajax call.

Also you need to a submit button to submit your form.

This should work assuming your action method is properly returning the partial view result without any errors.

```
<div id="YourDivToShowResult"></div>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("finalstatus", "User", null, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnSuccess = "popupappear()",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "YourDivToShowResult"

}, new { id = "progForm" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.SectionID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.CourseID)

    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly, although I don't need the submit button to submit the form as it is submitted using a javascript function on the click of the button.  I still have the issue that the onsuccess function is only being called on the second click of the button.  Any idea why that would be?

Comment: It was called everytime when i tried the above code. I had the submit button inside the form though. I am not sure what else you are doing in your code. Without that , It is hard to tell.

Comment: Fair enough, I will get to the bottom of it, thanks for your efforts.